# if Checkbox is checked then update calibrated = 'yes' and if Checkbox is not checked then update calibrated = 'no'

Tags: php, mysql

Hi Can you help me i have `check box name='calibrate',` now i want this if Checkbox is checked then update calibrated = 'yes' and if Checkbox is not checked then update `calibrated = 'no'.`

because the problem here is even i have `'Update machine_and_equipments set calibtrated = '$yah' where id = '$id'` it cannot update in database.

```
<?php
$res = mysql_query("select * from machine_and_equipments where id = '$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$cal = $row['21']; 
            $d1 = $row['6'];
    if($cal == "yes"){
        $checkthis = "<td >Need to Calibrate?: <input type='checkbox' name='calibrate'  onclick='OnChangeCheckbox(this), enable_text(this.checked)' id='myCheckbox' checked/><label  id='val'><?php echo $yah; ?></label> ";            
    }
    if($cal == "no"){
        $checkthis = "<td >Need to Calibrate?: <input type='checkbox' name='calibrate' onclick='OnChangeCheckbox(this), enable_text(this.checked)' id='myCheckbox' /> ";

    }

    if((isset($_POST['calibrate']))== "yes"){
    $yah = "yes";
    $id      = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "update machine_and_equipments set calibtrated = '$yah' where id = '$id'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die("could not be update". mysq_error());
    }
    if((isset($_POST['calibrate']))== "no"){
    $yah = "no";
    $id      = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "update machine_and_equipments set calibtrated = '$yah' where id = '$id'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die("could not be update". mysq_error());
    }
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I am not able to comment so i am writing this on answer. If it wont work let me know.

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {

   if((isset($_POST['calibrate']))){
     $yah = "yes";     
   } else {
    $yah = "no";    
   }
   $id      = $_POST['id'];
   $sql = "update machine_and_equipments set calibtrated = '$yah' where id = '$id'";
   $res = mysql_query($sql) or die("could not be update". mysq_error());
}
```

Comment: what do you get when you do echo $_POST['calibrate'] and what is the datatype of the column set calibrated.

Comment: hehe error 
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\KoushinEquipments\php\ME_EDIT.php on line 171 
and
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysq_error() in C:\wamp\www\KoushinEquipments\php\ME_EDIT.php on line 173

Comment: and ai dont know why id gives me error like that i said error :( i dont get it.